# IntelliJ Community edition hangs a lot while typing

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am using IntelliJ Community edition for for Automation test using Java. I have observed that IntelliJ stops responding for while when I am typing. Some times it takes like 1 to 2 minutes to respond while I type. Even it goes blank when I switch the windows between the applications.
I am using:

```
**OS:** Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit OS
**IntelliJ version:** 
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.8743.12, built on July 21, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b765.65 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: gherkin, cucumber-java
```

Does anybody is facing this issue?

Comment: please share complete log folder compressed including ThreadDump directory: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085

Comment: Where I can share the files?

Comment: please raise a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues with requested files attached